# Deploy a connection between two platforms' APIs

Tags: python, api, rest, deployment, live

I know this is not exactly the right type of questions for Stack overflow but I am struggling here and I would greatly appreciate your opinion(suggestions/advices) on the matter.

I am working on an script that works with APIs of two different websites (or even platforms). I have almost developed what I need but as calls to the APIs and information processing.

What my question is, how can I deploy this application online so that it works constantly without me having to keep my computer turned on so that it runs on it? In other words, where can I deploy this app on a server maybe and have it running all the time ? I know it is possible but I really cannot find quality information myself. So if you can either point me a direction or provide links, give advices, that would make my life a bit easier in finishing this project of mine.
Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: You need to detach or deaminize service.

Comment: You could put it on a Heroku server

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Pouya, correct me if I am wrong but I believe daemonizing a script/app is to make it a windows service rather than having it run on a server. This would mean that it will run when the computer is on which is the thing that I wanted to avoid.
Marcus, I will defo look into the Heroku suggestion. Thank you!